# Typescript Utility Types: Make all fields optional except for a few nested fields

Tags: typescript

I've looked through a lot of other related TS Utility Type questions and couldn't find something close enough to what I'm trying to do:

I have an interface, `Member` that looks like this:

```
export type Member = {
  __typename?: 'Member';
  group: Group;
  role: Role; // this is an enum
  user: User;
};
```

I'd like to define a type, Membership, where all of `Member` is optional, including the nested fields in `group` and `user` EXCEPT for a specific field inside `group` that needs to be required. I'd like the final type to look something like this:

```
type Membership = {
  __typename?: 'Member';
  role: Role;
  user? User;
  group: {
    name: string;
    // all other fields optional
  }
```

Is there a good solution to this without making a completely atrocious and unreadable utility type? Maybe utility types isn't the best solution?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a self-contains [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now the definitions for `Group`, `Role`, and `User` are ambiguous, and since recursive mapped types can have effects on every piece of a type, it might to things to `Group`, `Role`, and `User` you don't want.  Also I'm not sure how to understand why `role` is not optional in `Membership`; you said "all of `Member` is optional ... EXCEPT for a specific field inside `group`", so wouldn't `role` be optional?  A [mre] would help me provide a solution.

Comment: If you do decide to [edit] and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me